# How to Execute Powershell Pipeline Asynchronously

Tags: powershell, asynchronous, buffer, pipeline

How to make Powershell execute pipelines asynchronously instead of 'sequentially'?

An example to illustrate this:

```
Function PipeDelay($Name, $Miliseconds){
    Process {
        Sleep -miliseconds $Miliseconds
        Write-Host "$Name : $_"
        $_        
    }
}

1..7 | PipeDelay Fast 100 | PipeDelay Slow 300 | PipeDelay Slowest 900
```

The output in both ISE and powershell are the following:

```
Fast : 1
Slow : 1
Slowest : 1
1
Fast : 2
Slow : 2
Slowest : 2
2
Fast : 3
Slow : 3
Slowest : 3
3
...
```

It is as if Powershell sequentially run the whole pipeline for one input object before processing next input object. The execution looks something like this :

```
Fast    :  1                         2                         3
Slow    :    1---1                     2---2                     3---3
Slowest :          1---------------1         2---------------2         3-----...
```

Is it possible with some settings/environment variables/etc. to make pipelines to run independently/asynchronously? perhaps with setting about pipeline buffer size, etc.? So that the execution will looks something like this:

```
Fast    :  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
Slow    :    1---1 2---2 3---3 4---4 5---5 6---6 7---7
Slowest :          1---------------1 2---------------2 3-----...
```

*NOTE*

I thought it is because of STA/MTA mode. I don't understand them completely but same result in ISE (STA) / Powershell Shell (MTA) seems to eliminate STA/MTA mode as the cause.

Also, I thought `Write-Host` is the issue that force pipeline to be processed sequentially, but even if I substitute `Write-Host` with `New-Event`, the sequential processing still applies.

Comment: What you ask would not be easy, one of the benefits of the pipeline is that not all seven objects are in memory at one time; however the way you display it all seven would be cached by fast and wouldn't be resolved till slowest finishes. You'd need to build a throttle into the pipeline so if you're working with 5GB+ objects you don't outgrow your memory. `load-from-file | do-something-fast | do-something-slow | do-something-slowest | save-to-file`

Comment: Yup, agreed on the point that the pipeline needs to have some limit, whether explicit or implicit (default, fixed value). Thus, in question: "perhaps with setting about pipeline buffer size, etc.?"

Now, it seems Powershell have Foreach Parallel but it is only available in Workflow.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you will be able to leverage the pipeline in an asynchronous manner in the way you desire without being quiet expensive with resource usage. I tried to capture the spirit of what you are trying to accomplish, but in a different way. I used a slightly different example to illustrate how [Automation.PowerShell] Async works.

```
#1. You have a list of room requests you want to process in a function.  TimeToClean was added as a controllable thread block.
$roomsToClean = @( ([psCustomObject]@{Name='Bedroom';TimeToClean=2}),
                   ([psCustomObject]@{Name='Kitchen';TimeToClean=5}),
                   ([psCustomObject]@{Name='Bathroom';TimeToClean=3}),
                   ([psCustomObject]@{Name='Living room';TimeToClean=1}),
                   ([psCustomObject]@{Name='Dining room';TimeToClean=1}),
                   ([psCustomObject]@{Name='Foyier';TimeToClean=1})
                )


#2. We will clean three rooms and return a custom PowerShell object with a message.
Function Clean-Room{
     param([string]$RoomName,[int]$Seconds)
  
      Sleep -Seconds $Seconds
      Write-Output [psCustomObject] @{Message= "The robot cleaned the $RoomName in $Seconds seconds."}    
}


#3. Executing this list synchronously will result in an approximate 13 second runtime.
Write-Host "===== Synchronous Results =====" -ForegroundColor Green

$stopwatch =  [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()
foreach($item in $roomsToClean){
    $obj = Clean-Room $item.Name $item.TimeToClean
    Write-Output $obj.Message
}

$stopwatch.Stop()
Write-Host "Execution time for synchronous function was $($stopwatch.Elapsed)." -ForegroundColor Green


#4. Now let's run this function asynchronously for all of these items. Expected runtime will be approximately 5 seconds.


#=============== Setting up an ansynchronous powerShell Automation object and attaching it to a runspace.
#Many [Automation.PowerShell] objects can be attached to a given Runspace pool and the Runspace pool will manage queueing/dequeueing of each PS object as it completes.

#Create a RunSpace pool with 5 runspaces.  The pool will manage the 
#Many PowerShell autom
$minRunSpaces = 2
$maxRunsSpaces = 5
$runspacePool = [RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspacePool($minRunSpaces, $maxRunsSpaces)    
$runspacePool.ApartmentState = 'STA'   #MTA = Multithreaded apartment  #STA = Singl-threaded apartment.
$runspacePool.Open()  #runspace pool must be opened before it can be used.

#For each room object, create an [Automation.PowerShell] object and attach it to the runspace pool.
#Asynchronously invoke the function for all objects in the collection.
$ps_collections = foreach($room in $roomsToClean){
                    try{
                
                    $ps = [System.Management.Automation.PowerShell]::Create() 
                    $ps.RunspacePool = $runspacePool

                    #Add your custom functions to the [Automation.PowerShell] object.
                    #Add argument with parameter name for readability. You may just use AddArgument as an alternative but know your positional arguments.

                    [void] $ps.AddScript(${function:Clean-Room})
                    [void] $ps.AddParameter('RoomName',$room.Name)        #Add parameterName,value
                    [void] $ps.AddParameter('Seconds',$room.TimeToClean)  #Add parameterName,value

                    #extend the ps management object to include AsyncResult and attach the AsyncResult object for receiving results at a later time.
                    $ps | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name 'AsyncResult' -Value $ps.BeginInvoke()  #invoke asynchronously
                    $ps | Add-Member -MemberType ScriptMethod -Name 'GetAsyncResult' -Value {$this.EndInvoke($this.AsyncResult) } -PassThru
                    }
                    catch{
                        throw $_  #handle custom error here.
                    }
                }



        
#After the function has been asynchronously called for all room objects, Grab results from asynchronous function calls.
Write-Host "===== Asynchronous Results =====" -ForegroundColor Green
$stopwatch =  [system.diagnostics.stopwatch]::StartNew()
foreach($ps in $ps_collections){
    $obj = $ps.GetAsyncResult()
    [void] $ps.Dispose()  #dispose of object after use.
    Write-Output $obj.Message
}

$stopwatch.Stop()
Write-Host "Execution time for asynchronous function was 
$($stopwatch.Elapsed)." -ForegroundColor Green

#Runspace cleanup.
If($runspacePool){
    [void] $runspacePool.Close()
    [void] $runspacePool.Dispose()
}
```

Result times will vary slightly but should look similar to this:

```
===== Synchronous Results =====
The robot cleaned the Bedroom in 2 seconds.
The robot cleaned the Kitchen in 5 seconds. 
The robot cleaned the Bathroom in 3 seconds.
The robot cleaned the Living room in 1 seconds.
The robot cleaned the Dining room in 1 seconds.
The robot cleaned the Foyier in 1 seconds.
Execution time for synchronous function was 00:00:13.0719157.
```

```
####===== Asynchronous Results =====
The robot cleaned the Bedroom in 2 seconds.
The robot cleaned the Kitchen in 5 seconds.
The robot cleaned the Bathroom in 3 seconds.
The robot cleaned the Living room in 1 seconds.
The robot cleaned the Dining room in 1 seconds. 
The robot cleaned the Foyier in 1 seconds.
Execution time for asynchronous function was 00:00:04.9909951.
```